# Preventing touch from passing through CCLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCLayer which I'm using as a pause menu. It takes over the entire screen, but currently allows touch to pass through it.

I'd like to prevent touches from passing through it, but I'm having a bit of difficulty. Here's what I have:

```
-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        self = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(11, 153, 223, 255) width: s.width height: s.height];
        self.position = CGPointZero;
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];

    }
    return self;
}
```

However, touches on the layer cause a crash, but also seem to be able to pass through it.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layer#ccTouchBegan override me'
```

What's the easiest way to prevent touches from passing through this cclayer? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After add layer as targeted touch delegate, you must implement CCTargetedTouchDelegate methods. At least

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

this method is required. Other are optional. And you should not add layer as touch delegate in such way. There is a method in CCLayer class

```
- (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
```

Override it and place there your line

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

If you want to pass touches through this layer in some time, you can just write this line

```
[myLayer setIsTouchEnabled: NO];
```

Or if you want to catch touches in some rect, you must implement your logic in `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:` method. If this method returns `NO`, this touch can be handled by any other touch delegate. If this method returns `YES`, this touch will be not delivered to any other touch delegate

Comment: I think sharedDispatcher has been depreciated and I switched to this: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all cocos2d layers are in one, sigle UIView, and all touches are catche not be this layers, but by this UIView.
To prevent touches you may try to remove delegate from `CCTouchDicpatcher`, of set layer's `isTouchEnabled` property to `NO`.